# I want to fetch data into in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to show data in jquery script but I don't know how can I fetch the record in jquery script please help me thanks.

**response**

[image]

**jquery script**

```
  // initialize playlist and controls
      var index = 0,
          playing = false,
          mediaPath = '{{url('')}}/assets/al-quran/',
          extension = '',
          tracks = [
                  {
                  "track": "<i class='fa fa-headphones'></i>",
                  "name": "001 Surah-Al-Fatiha ",
                  "duration": "<span><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> 150 | <i class='fa fa-download'></i> 120</span> <i class='fa fa-play-circle'></i>",
                  "file": "001-surah-al-fatiha"
                  }
            ],
          buildPlaylist = $.each(tracks, function(key, value) {
              var trackNumber = value.track,
                  trackName = value.name,
                  trackDuration = value.duration;
              if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                  trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
              }
              $('#plList').append('<li> \
                  <div class="plItem"> \
                      <span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '</span> \
                      <span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span> \
                      <span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span> \
                  </div> \
              </li>');
          });
```

Comment: read this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: What do you want to do?  your question is not clear at all....

Comment: Click edit. Then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and include the object in a [mcve].  NO LARAVEL PHP in the code. Just RENDERED HTML and script

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start

You need the object and call it obj

```js
const tracks = obj.map(item => ({
  "track": "<i class='fa fa-headphones'></i>",
  "name": `${item.id} ${item.para_name}`,
  "duration": "unknown",
  "file": item.audio_file
}));


// initialize playlist and controls
var index = 0,
  playing = false,
  mediaPath = '{{url('')}}/assets/al-quran/';

tracks.forEach(item =>
var trackNumber = item.track,
  trackName = item.name,
  trackDuration = item.duration;
if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
  trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
}
$('#plList').append(`<li class="plItem">
  <span class="plNum">${trackNumber}</span>
  <span class="plTitle">${trackName}</span>
  <span class="plLength">${trackDuration}</span>
</li>`);
});
```